# WSO2 Governance Tag

Tags: java, tags, wso2

I've uploaded a good amount of resources into WSO2 governance with a Java program and automatically uploaded the Tags with registry.applyTag(resourcePath, "svc");

My plan is to grab all the services off of WSO2 with another Java program that checks which resources have this tag (which, ideally, would be all) so that I can export an XML from them. (with this code: registry.getResourcePathsWithTag("svc")) Not sure if this is the right approach, but it's the only one I could come up with.

My question is, is there a way to automatically set this Tag from the "Add" screen in the Management Console? I know you can go back to Browse and add it there, but I don't want to forget this tag and other user will be adding services.

Any suggestions on how to do this? or a better way to export the metadata from WSO2 other than searching for tags?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add specific tag for each service you are going to add, you can use registry handlers. When resource is inserting( `put` operation), you can add custom tag for it.

Please refer [Handler Sample](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance460/Handler+Sample) documentation.

Comment: Blog(Apply Tags using Handler): http://cnapagoda.blogspot.com/2014/02/wso2-governance-registry-apply-tags.html